# iOS UISearchBar:Set showsScopeBar=YES & scopeButtonTitles is not nil , but scopeBar no show

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am going to crazy!Here is my issue.I want to show the `UISearchBar.ScopeBar` when I begin to search and hide it after searched.I found a solution post in 
[iPhone : hide a scopeBar from a searchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954007/iphone-hide-a-scopebar-from-a-searchbar/3958766#3958766)
but it not work for me.
Here is my codes:

```
   self.friendSearchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Phone",@"Name", nil];
   self.friendSearchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0;
   self.friendSearchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to have the search bar disappear after you search you need to implement this.

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
YourScopeGoesHere scopeKey = controller.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex;
[self searchForText:searchString scope:scopeKey];
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
NSString *searchString = controller.searchBar.text;
[self searchForText:searchString scope:searchOption];
return YES;
}
```